# authorize net error 39 using cim library in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authorize.net

Every time I create a customer profile id I get the response below from authorize net, but there is not a duplicate because it is newly created customer profile. Since I am retrieving the user's email to create the authorizenet profile id I already checked the mysql database for duplicated rows, but there are none. I am using authorize.net's latest php sdk.

```
AuthorizeNetCIM_Response Object
(
    [xml] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [messages] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [resultCode] =&gt; Error
                    [message] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [code] =&gt; E00039
                            [text] =&gt; A duplicate record with ID 31985206 already exists.
                        )

            )

        [customerPaymentProfileIdList] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [customerShippingAddressIdList] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [validationDirectResponseList] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )

[response] =&gt; ï»¿
```

I am using an email confirmation in Codeigniter to create the Authorizenet customer id

```
 public function email_confirmation(){

    //passes the post user id variable to a local variable  
    $username=$this->uri->segment(3);

    //activate user account when confirmed
    $confirmation=$this->register_customer_model->user_confirms_email($username);
    //$confirmation = TRUE;

                         if($confirmation==TRUE){

                                 //load authorizenet model
                                 $this->load->model('authorizenet_model');

                                 //create authorizenet profile id
                                 $response=$this->authorizenet_model->create_authorizenet_profile_id($username);

                                 print_r($response);
```

}

Here is the authorizenet model to create the profile id with the user's username

```
public function create_authorizenet_profile_id($username){

    //get email from username    
    $query=$this->db->query("
    SELECT email
    FROM   users
    WHERE  username='$username'");

   foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $email                = $row->email;
                                     }

                                  //creates authorizenet profile id                                    
                                  $request                      = new AuthorizeNetCIM;
                                  $customerProfile              = new AuthorizeNetCustomer;
                                  $customerProfile->description = "Bar Express Customer";
                                  $customerProfile->email       = $email;

                                  $response = $request->createCustomerProfile($customerProfile);

                                  return $response;                                
                                                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the order the request is made. It should be

```
// Create new customer profile
$customerProfile                     = new AuthorizeNetCustomer;
$customerProfile->description        = "Description of customer";
$customerProfile->merchantCustomerId = time();
$customerProfile->email              = "test@domain.com";
$response = $request->createCustomerProfile($customerProfile);
if ($response->isOk()) {
    $customerProfileId = $response->getCustomerProfileId();
}
```